# Why the term "diverse" can be used in singular form?

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural

According to Collins, the meaning of the term "diverse" is *"If a group or range of things is diverse, it is made up of a wide variety of things"* so it seems it can be used to explain multiple things.

But I sometimes can see the use of the word like "a diverse sample" to show singular thing. Why the term "diverse" can be used in singular form?

Comment: The term diverse is an adjective. Adjectives can qualify either singular or plural nouns. For example *red*: *There is a red apple on the table, or there are red apples on the table*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to Collins, the meaning of the term "diverse" is "If a group or range of things is diverse, it is made up of a wide variety of things" so it seems it can be used to explain multiple things.

"group", "range", and "variety" are all singular nouns. They *refer* to things that have lots of members, but grammatically they are singular. Similarly, "sample" is grammatically singular, but it refers to something that includes several different elements. Diversity is a property of a set, not the members of the set. It's a collective property that refers to the relationship between the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Diverse is an adjective that can be used to talk about both singular and plural nouns.

Examples of "diverse" with singular nouns:

> We have a **diverse** *selection* of products for sale. 
>   Your *taste in art* is quite **diverse**

Examples of "diverse" with plural nouns:

> The *students* in this school are very **diverse**. 
>   Your *paintings* are really **diverse**.